# Laravel Eloquent Relationships on 3 tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Please i have 3 tables that i want to display but 3 of the tables are related.

The first table is `GROUPS`, second is `CONTACTS`, and the last is `PHONE_NUMBERS`.

I am using Laravel Framework. The problem is, i don't know the eloquent relation to use, i want to display content of the the `GROUPS` table, while the `CONTACTS` will display under the `GROUPS` and the `PHONE NUMBERS` will display under the `CONTACTS`.

Please advice me on how to achieve this.
Attached is an image of how it will look when finished.

[image]

Comment: Man...you should really consider rewriting you question. If you can't just express human thought clearly, concisely, and understandable, I'm afraid there's even harder jumping into to some code or query :)

Comment: @JimRaynor The description may be a little convoluted, but the image is pretty self explanatory :).

Comment: @Bogdan I know :) I saw the image before leaving the comment. Just after some simple editing, the question is already much more at least readable. Yet it was edited by the community, not by the asker - which I wish he'd take a look back at his question and try to do the revision himself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each group can have multiple contacts, and each contact can have multiple phone numbers, you'll need to define one-to-many relation from group to contact and from contact to phone number:

```
class Group extends Model {
  public function contacts() {
    return $this->hasMany(Contact::class);
  }
}

class Contact extends Model {
  public function phoneNumbers() {
    return $this->hasMany(PhoneNumber::class);
  }
}
```

With relations defined, you will be able to load groups, their contacts and contacts' phone numbers with:

```
$groups  = Group::with(['contacts', 'contacts.phoneNumbers'])->get();
```

This will give you a collection of groups. Each of groups will contain a collection of contacts in their **contacts** property. Each of contacts will contain phone numbers collection in their **phoneNumbers** properties. By iterating through those collections you should be able to get data needed to render the structure you need, e.g.:

```
@foreach($groups as $group)
  {{ $group->name }}
  @foreach ($group->contacts as $contact)
    {{ $contact->name }}
    @foreach ($contact->phoneNumbers as $number)
      {{ $number->number }}
    @endforeach
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

All necessary information on how to model your data with Eloquent can be found in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent

Comment: Thank you so much @jedrzej.kurylo