# Laravel Eloquent Relationships 3 tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have three db tables. The first is PROJEKTS, the second table is USERS, and the third table is ACTIVITIES. The tables are related. There are multiple users under each project, and there are activities under each user.
A similar project is addressed here: [Laravel Eloquent Relationships on 3 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706567/laravel-eloquent-relationships-on-3-tables)
I need Laravel Controller. Load only one specific project with users where each user can have activities.

```
class Projekts extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function activity()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Activities');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the three models and the relevant relationships.

Comment: I added models
I wrote relationships

Comment: Please fix the relationship names. You want to select all of a project's users and their activities?

Comment: I repaired
I need one record = one project with all users and all activities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
$projekt = Projekts::with('user.activity')->find($id);
foreach($projekt->user as $user) {
    foreach($user->activity as $activity) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Now I want to create a new project with users. The form is with the inputs for the project model and the inputs for the model users.  <br/>
This code will save Projects:  <br/>
    $newProjects = \App\Projects\create ($request->all());
How do I save users?  <br/>
  <br/>
Can the project be saved together with the users who belong to the new project?

Comment: I need to save a project and several activities

Comment: You create the project, then its users and the users' activities.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. I want to know if there is a simpler code.

```
    $form = $request->all();

    $newproject = \App\Projects::create( $form );
    $newproject_Id = $newproject->id;

    foreach ($form['items'] as $item) {
        $user= new \App\User;
            $user->projects_id = $novafaktura_Id;
            $user->nic = $item['name'];
            $user-> ...and other
        $user->save();
    }
```